# How to select the best fit machine learning algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

while frequently running the machine learning algorithms the accuracy is changing in that case how to select the best fit algorithm for that particular data set.

Comment: How can I buy the best flavor of ice cream? Welcome to stackoverflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and have fun out here!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely provide more details. It's impossible to suggest anything without the domain, the model architecture, hyperparameters.

I guess you are complaining due to changing of accuracy of the model. I think you should set seeds for randomized parameters so that accuracy don't change while training different times and you can reproduce your results.

```
numpy.random.seed(1)
random.seed(1)
tf.random.set_random_seed(1) # if using tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume , the question is for the same data set X (Training), everytime when we run the accuracy by comparing the predicted responses against our Testdata Dependent values(Y) .
If the accuracy keeps changing if we run the model seems, the issue is Sampling Bias ( the division of Training and Test data upholds a mystery).

When you import train_test_split function , use the random_state attribute wisely to keep the test data representative for the overall population of data.

Comment: Even I use random_state attribute the accuracy is changing,then how fix it.

Comment: As the details are not mentioned, it could be due to stochastic nature of the algorithm if it is used,training or test data couldnt represent the whole picture. Get more sample data and scrap the existing model and recreate it.

Comment: For more details, please refer https://machinelearningmastery.com/the-model-performance-mismatch-problem/.